# Fillout form in IE using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Looking to fill out a form in IE from a specific cell on my sheet; research has brought me to:

```
Function FillInternetForm()
  Dim ie As Object
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Navigate     "http://helppointinfo.farmersinsurance.com/OCR/Labor_Rates/laborrates.asp"
'go to web page listed inside quotes
  ie.Visible = True
  While ie.Busy
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
  Wend
  ie.Document.all("RatesForm").Value = Sheets("NAT").Range("C2").Value

End Function
```

***UPDATED***

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0" />
    <title>Labor Rates</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //Function is called when Enter Zip text box is changed or when Drill down zip is selected
        function FindRates() {
            if (document.RatesForm.DirectZip.value + "Empty" != "Empty" && document.RatesForm.ZipDD.value + "Empty" != "Empty") {
                if (ValidateZip()) {
                    document.RatesForm.StateDD.value = ""
                    var strZipCode = document.RatesForm.ZipDD.value
                    document.getElementById("ErrorZip").style.display = "None"
                    document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME").item("DisplayReport").src = "RatesHandler.asp?ZipCode=" + strZipCode
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("ErrorZip").style.display = "Block"
                }
            }
            else if (document.RatesForm.DirectZip.value + "Empty" != "Empty") {

                if (ValidateZip()) {
                    document.RatesForm.StateDD.value = ""
                    var strZipCode = document.RatesForm.DirectZip.value
                    document.getElementById("ErrorZip").style.display = "None"
                    document.RatesForm.submit();
                    document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME").item("DisplayReport").src = "RatesHandler.asp?ZipCode=" + strZipCode
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("ErrorZip").style.display = "Block"
                }
            }
        }
        //Function called when State is selected from state Drop Down
        function StateRates() {
            var strState = document.RatesForm.StateDD.value
            document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME").item("DisplayReport").src = "RatesHandler.asp?State=" + strState
            document.RatesForm.DirectZip.value = ""
            document.RatesForm.ZipDD.value = ""
            document.getElementById("ErrorZip").style.display = "None"
            document.getElementById("TabTag").style.display = "None"
        }
        //Function Disables the Drill Down Zip to stop a double function issue
        function disableDD() {
            document.RatesForm.ZipDD.disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("TabTag").style.display = "Block"
        }
        function ValidateZip() {
            var re = /^\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?$/;
            var testBool = re.test(document.RatesForm.DirectZip.value);
            return (testBool);
        }
        function disableEnterKey(e) {
            var key;
            if (window.event)
                key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
            else
                key = e.which;     //firefox
            if (key == 13)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }


    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />


  </head>

    <body>

<div class="DocumentTitle">Labor Rates Lookup</div>
<form name="RatesForm" method="post" >
    <table class="SearchTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="SearchHeader">
            <td colspan="2" >By Zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="SearchRow">
            <td>Enter Zip <br /><input class="SearchInput" id="DirectZip" name="DirectZip" value="" onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)" onblur="FindRates();" onfocus="disableDD();"  /></td>
            <td>
                <span style="display:block;">Drill Down Zip<br />

                    <select disabled = "disabled" id="Select1" name="ZipDD" class="SearchSelect" style="width:200px;"onchange="FindRates();">
                        <option class='SearchSelect' selected='selected'>Please Enter Zip</option>
                    <option class='SearchSelect' selected='selected'></option>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="SearchRow" style="text-align:center"><td colspan="2"><span id="ErrorZip" style="display:none;color:Red;">Please Enter a Valid US Zip Code!</span></td></tr>
        <tr class="SearchRow" style="text-align:center"><td colspan="2"><span id="TabTag" style="display:none">Enter Zip Code and hit Tab.</span></td></tr>

        <tr class="SearchHeader">
            <td  colspan="2" >By State</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="SearchRow">
            <td   colspan="2" style="text-align:center;" >
                <select id="ByState" name="StateDD" class="SearchSelect" onchange="StateRates();">
                    <option selected="selected"></option>

                        <option value = "AL" style='width:98%'>Alabama</option>

                        <option value = "AK" style='width:98%'>Alaska</option>

                        <option value = "AZ" style='width:98%'>Arizona</option>

                        <option value = "AR" style='width:98%'>Arkansas</option>

                        <option value = "CA" style='width:98%'>California</option>

                        <option value = "CO" style='width:98%'>Colorado</option>

                        <option value = "CT" style='width:98%'>Connecticut</option>

                        <option value = "DE" style='width:98%'>Delaware</option>

                        <option value = "DC" style='width:98%'>Dist. Columbia</option>

                        <option value = "FL" style='width:98%'>Florida</option>

                        <option value = "GA" style='width:98%'>Georgia</option>

                        <option value = "HI" style='width:98%'>Hawaii</option>

                        <option value = "ID" style='width:98%'>Idaho</option>

                        <option value = "IL" style='width:98%'>Illinois</option>

                        <option value = "IN" style='width:98%'>Indiana</option>

                        <option value = "IA" style='width:98%'>Iowa</option>

                        <option value = "KS" style='width:98%'>Kansas</option>

                        <option value = "KY" style='width:98%'>Kentucky</option>

                        <option value = "LA" style='width:98%'>Louisiana</option>

                        <option value = "ME" style='width:98%'>Maine</option>

                        <option value = "MD" style='width:98%'>Maryland</option>

                        <option value = "MA" style='width:98%'>Massachusetts</option>

                        <option value = "MI" style='width:98%'>Michigan</option>

                        <option value = "MN" style='width:98%'>Minnesota</option>

                        <option value = "MS" style='width:98%'>Mississippi</option>

                        <option value = "MO" style='width:98%'>Missouri</option>

                        <option value = "MT" style='width:98%'>Montana</option>

                        <option value = "NE" style='width:98%'>Nebraska</option>

                        <option value = "NV" style='width:98%'>Nevada</option>

                        <option value = "NH" style='width:98%'>New Hampshire</option>

                        <option value = "NJ" style='width:98%'>New Jersey</option>

                        <option value = "NM" style='width:98%'>New Mexico</option>

                        <option value = "NY" style='width:98%'>New York</option>

                        <option value = "NC" style='width:98%'>North Carolina</option>

                        <option value = "ND" style='width:98%'>North Dakota</option>

                        <option value = "OH" style='width:98%'>Ohio</option>

                        <option value = "OK" style='width:98%'>Oklahoma</option>

                        <option value = "OR" style='width:98%'>Oregon</option>

                        <option value = "PA" style='width:98%'>Pennsylvania</option>

                        <option value = "RI" style='width:98%'>Rhode Island</option>

                        <option value = "SC" style='width:98%'>South Carolina</option>

                        <option value = "SD" style='width:98%'>South Dakota</option>

                        <option value = "TN" style='width:98%'>Tennessee</option>

                        <option value = "TX" style='width:98%'>Texas</option>

                        <option value = "UN" style='width:98%'>Unknown</option>

                        <option value = "UT" style='width:98%'>Utah</option>

                        <option value = "VT" style='width:98%'>Vermont</option>

                        <option value = "VA" style='width:98%'>Virginia</option>

                        <option value = "WA" style='width:98%'>Washington</option>

                        <option value = "WV" style='width:98%'>West Virginia</option>

                        <option value = "WI" style='width:98%'>Wisconsin</option>

                        <option value = "WY" style='width:98%'>Wyoming</option>

                </select>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div>
    <iframe name="DisplayReport" id="DisplayReport" src="LaborCover.asp" frameborder="0"  style="LEFT: 0%; WIDTH: 75%; TOP: 0%; HEIGHT:550px; BACKGROUND-COLOR:#CCCCCC; border:solid 0px black;"></IFRAME>
</div>
</body>
```

Banging my head against the wall on why I keep getting an error on the ie.document.all

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "an error" - what error?

Comment: **bold**Run-time error '91':

Comment: **Object variable or With block variable not set**
then highlights
    ie.Document.all("RatesForm").Value = Sheets("NAT").Range("C2").Value

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments - 1st posts and subsequent comments

Comment: The error suggests that either there's no element named `RatesForm`, or no sheet named `NAT`.  It would help to post the relevant HTML.

Comment: <form name="RatesForm" method="post" >

I believe in order for above to work I need to reference the form I am wanting the information in excel to fill, correct? Am I looking at this incorrectly? I have full confidence in the name of the sheet

Comment: Need the full HTML for the form element you want to fill, not just the form itself.  Better if you update your question to add it.

Comment: Which of those form fields are you trying to set the value for?

Comment: I believe I am trying to fill RatesForm under the "Enter Zip" table.

Background - I've created a national database defined by zip codes. I'm moving this table from excel access to html access. However, there are several tools that are still used on the excel sheet. My hope is to still use the excel sheet to enter in the zip, with that datapoint being delivered to the html site and populating the information.

This is just the first phase, eventually I'd like to be able to draw that information back into the excel sheet.

Comment: `ie.Document.GetElementById("DirectZip").Value = Sheets("NAT").Range("C2").Value`

Comment: That did it! What in the HTML code signified this information for you?

Comment: When trying to fill in a value to a form element, you need to first get a reference to it: you can either use something like `ie.document.formName.elementName` (because all form elements typically have a Name attribute) or if it has an id assigned you can use `getElementById` (typically safer, since there should be only on element with any given id, whereas Name can repeat)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selector:**

Piggybacking of the answer in the comment you can also use a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) of `#DirectZip`.
This read as element with id of `DirectZip`.  `#` means id.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS selector]

---

**VBA:**

You use the [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of document to apply the CSS selector:

```
.document.querySelector("#DirectZip")
```